# Verification of precipitation forecast R package

Tags: r

I have observed and simulated precipitation. I want to use the `verification` packages to verify the skill of of the model.

For this I have to convert the `pred` value into a probabilistic forecast and the `obs` into binary. For instances for the `precipitation amount>2mm`. That is to use tho following script

```
A<- verify(obs, pred, frcst.type = "prob", obs.type = "binary")

summary(A)
```

My question is how to convert `pred` into probabilistic and `obs` into binary to use the above script

The length of my data is 122. Here is the data.

```
> Obs

 [1]   1.9  3.7  3.4  1.1  1.0  1.0  0.6  2.8  1.4  1.9  1.6  1.3  3.6  3.6  3.9

 [16]   3.4  2.7  5.9  3.8  1.8  2.2  2.5  2.6  2.4  2.6  1.5  1.0 11.2  2.1  0.6

 [31]  1.8  3.8  4.0  1.3  2.4  2.9  3.9  2.7  1.1  2.6  0.6  2.5  3.1  4.9  3.2

 [46]  2.1  3.6  0.1  2.4  2.3  3.7  0.6  4.0 12.5  4.3  2.3  3.0  3.4  2.3  2.1

 [61]  3.9  2.6  1.9  2.0  3.7  2.2  0.7  0.2  2.5  2.8  4.1  4.2  3.1  5.9  2.8

 [76]  2.1  3.7  1.2  2.3  2.6  6.3  1.9  2.9  6.3  7.1  4.0  5.3  1.1  2.5  3.6

 [91]  5.7  2.9  1.9  0.9  3.0  2.0  1.6  3.3  4.5  4.3  3.3  2.0  0.6  0.9  0.6

[106]  1.1  1.2  2.7  0.5  3.1  1.2  0.1  0.5  1.3  0.7  3.1  2.4  2.7  1.1  1.7

[121]  3.5  2.2

> Pred

  [1]  0.3  0.7 1.6 4.8 2.2 2.4 1.8 3.1 3.4 2.2 3.0 1.0 0.5 1.2 1.4 1.4 0.7 0.9

 [19] 1.6 1.0 0.8 0.6 1.2 1.7 1.9 2.6 2.7 2.7 5.8 9.4 5.3 3.4 4.1 3.9 3.0 2.8

 [37] 3.7 4.6 6.3 3.3 3.0 4.6 3.8 4.1 3.2 3.4 5.3 7.5 5.9 3.4 2.1 2.6 2.7 3.4

 [55] 5.4 9.7 5.9 3.6 2.9 2.6 2.0 2.9 4.2 5.1 4.2 3.0 3.5 5.2 3.7 3.2 3.2 3.7

 [73] 3.1 4.5 4.8 3.8 6.1 5.3 4.8 8.1 5.9 4.8 6.3 6.6 8.4 6.6 4.8 4.3 1.3 1.3

 [91] 3.1 4.5 2.8 3.6 3.6 4.2 3.6 4.1 3.2 3.4 3.8 3.1 2.4 1.6 0.6 1.3 2.1 1.9

[109] 2.0 1.9 1.5 1.1 0.8 0.9 1.7 1.0 0.7 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.6 2.1
```

Comment: Could you tell exactly where is a problem with this line: A<- verify(obs, pred, frcst.type = "prob", obs.type = "binary") I checked it, and it worked fine. I don't understand why you need to convert your data?

Comment: Dear Bochenek, Thank for your answer. If you observed R verification packages to calculate Brier Score, roc.area, hit rate and false alarm rate, it needs obs.type=bin, and pred.type=prob. But the data I have both obs and pred are continous. That is why I want to convert

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the options to continuous data? 
A<- verify(obs, pred, frcst.type = "cont", obs.type = "cont")

If you want to convert obs to binary, that is pretty easy. Just replace all values larger than 2mm with 1 and all values smaller than 2mm with 0. 
obs[which(obs=>2)]<-1
obs[which(obs<2)]<-0
You could do the same for the forecast, but then your forecast type is binary, too. Otherwise you would have to adapt your forecast model in a way that it predicts the probability of the rainfall to be larger than 2mm, rather than predicting the actual rainfall. You would have to switch from a deterministic to a probabilistic model.